# Как понять к какому объекту относится инпут?

Tags: python, django

После каждого раздела добавил инпут, в котором юзер указывает требуемое количество вопросов относящихся к конкретному разделу, что бы в дальнейшем вытащить требуемое количество вопросов из базы и отобразить.

Выглядит так:

[image]

Как мне определять к какому разделу(объекту из базы) относится инпут(chekbox или text)?

Вот код шаблона

```
 <form action="/vibor_test/gener/" method ="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
    <ol>
        {% recursetree nodes.get_descendants %}
            <li>
                {{ node.name }}
                {% if node.level == 1 %}
                    <input type="text" name="text" value="" >
                {% endif %}
                {% if node.level == 2 %}
                    <input type="checkbox" name=""  value="">
                {% endif %}
                {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                    <ol class="children">
                        {{ children}}
                    </ol>
                {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endrecursetree %}
    </ol>
     <input class="button"  type="submit" value="Пройти тест">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В шаблоне:

```
<input type="text" name="text_{{ node.id }}" >
```

views.py:

```
textbox_list = [x for x in request.POST if x.startswith('text_')]
 args['id'] = textbox_list[0].replace('text_', '')
```

Comment: Подскажите, это дополнение к вопросу или ответ?